# Copy / blend images of different sizes using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to blend two images. It is easy if they have the same size, but if one of the images is smaller or larger cv::addWeighted fails.

Image A (expected to be larger)
Image B (expected to be smaller)

I tried to create a ROI - tried to create a third image of the size of A and copy B inside - I can't seem to get it right. Please help.

```
double alpha = 0.7; // something
int min_x = ( A.cols - B.cols)/2 );
int min_y = ( A.rows - B.rows)/2 );
int width, height;
if(min_x < 0) {
  min_x = 0; width = (*input_images).at(0).cols - 1;
}
else         width = (*input_images).at(1).cols - 1;
if(min_y < 0) {
  min_y = 0; height = (*input_images).at(0).rows - 1;
}
else         height = (*input_images).at(1).rows - 1;
cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(min_x, min_y, width, height);            
cv::Mat larger_image(A);
// not sure how to copy B into roi, or even if it is necessary... and keep the images the same size
cv::addWeighted( larger_image, alpha, A, 1-alpha, 0.0, out_image, A.depth());
```

Even something like cvSetImageROI - may work but I can't find the c++ equivalent - may help - but I don't know how to use it to still keep the image content, only place another image inside ROI...

Comment: Do you want `out_image` to be (1) a cropped part of `A` blended with `B` (thus the size of `B`) or (2) the size of `A` with a selected part blended with `B` (thus the size of `A`)?

Comment: The size of A - with a selected section blended with B

Comment: Why is `width = (*input_images).at(0).cols - 1`? Why not `(*input_images).at(0).cols`?

Comment: @Thalia, could you tell what is `*input_images` that you assign to `height` and `width` inside `if` statements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// min_x, min_y should be valid in A and [width height] = size(B)
cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(min_x, min_y, B.cols, B.rows);  

// "out_image" is the output ; i.e. A with a part of it blended with B
cv::Mat out_image = A.clone();

// Set the ROIs for the selected sections of A and out_image (the same at the moment)
cv::Mat A_roi= A(roi);
cv::Mat out_image_roi = out_image(roi);

// Blend the ROI of A with B into the ROI of out_image
cv::addWeighted(A_roi,alpha,B,1-alpha,0.0,out_image_roi);
```

Note that if you want to blend `B` directly into `A`, you just need `roi`.

```
cv::addWeighted(A(roi),alpha,B,1-alpha,0.0,A(roi));
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error as I have always gotten: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar op array'  in unknown function, ...\arithm.cpp, line 1277

Comment: Try `cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(min_x, min_y, B.cols, B.rows);  `

Comment: It sort of worked - thank you - except the result is image A resized to the size of image B - and the two blended together.  I used A(roi) as output

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you ! and I have a better understanding of roi now.

Comment: @Jacob Nice explanation. Google brought me here. :D

Comment: Useful code, but could you help me with a little problem - I got output window, which size is like the smaller image? I checked `out_image_roi.size()` and it's size is equal to smaller image, which is wrong. How to fix it?

Answer (score -5):

You can easily blend two images using `addWeighted()`function

```
addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0, dst);
```

Declare two images

```
src1 = imread("c://test//blend1.jpg");
src2 = imread("c://test//blend2.jpg");
```

Declare the value of `alpha` and `beta` and then call the function. You are done. You can find the details in the link: [Blending of Images using Opencv](http://www.life2coding.com/blending-images-using-opencv/)