# opencv draw transparent image onto another image

Tags: c++, opencv

I know there are two methods in opencv called copyTo() and addWeighted(), but that does not meet my need.

Currently, I have a background image (4 channels), and a small image with a transparent hole in the center. If I use copyTo() method, some image info of the background image will be lost, if I use addWeighted(), the center transparent part will get a little bit blurred.

How can I just "draw" the transparent image to the background image?

Comment: It's not very clear. Can you please post the images, and the expected result? However, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32481105/5008845) should help

Answer (score 0):

make a new image that is a clone of the background image `backImg.clone();` then use `copyTo()` with the small image on the cloned image then display it. 
Is that what you want?