# how to flatten 2 different image layers?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have 2 Mat objects, `overlay` and `background`.

How do I put my `overlay` Mat on top of my `background` Mat such that only the non-transparent pixels of the `overlay` Mat completely obscures the `background` Mat?

I have tried `addWeighted()` which combines the 2 Mat but both "layers" are still visible.

- The `overlay` Mat has a transparent channel while the `background` Mat does not.
- The pixel in the `overlay` Mat is either completely transparent or fully obscure.
- Both Mats are of the same size.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32481105/5008845), you should get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to port api55's edited answer for java:

```
private void merge(Mat background, Mat overlay) {
            List<Mat> backgroundChannels = new ArrayList<>();
            Core.split(background, backgroundChannels);

        List<Mat> overlayChannels = new ArrayList<>();
        Core.split(overlay, overlayChannels);

        // compute "alphaRate = 1 - overlayAlpha / 255"
        Mat overlayAlphaChannel = overlayChannels.get(3);
        Mat alphaRate = new Mat(overlayAlphaChannel.size(), overlayAlphaChannel.type());
        Core.divide(overlayAlphaChannel, new Scalar(255), alphaRate);
        Core.absdiff(alphaRate, new Scalar(1), alphaRate);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // compute "(1 - alphaRate) * overlay"
            Mat overlayChannel = overlayChannels.get(i);
            Mat temp = new Mat(alphaRate.size(), alphaRate.type());
            Core.absdiff(alphaRate, new Scalar(1), temp);
            Core.multiply(temp, overlayChannel, overlayChannel);
            temp.release();

            // compute "background * alphaRate"
            Mat backgroundChannel = backgroundChannels.get(i);
            Core.multiply(backgroundChannel, alphaRate, backgroundChannel);

            // compute the merged channel
            Core.add(backgroundChannel, overlayChannel, backgroundChannel);
        }

        alphaRate.release();
        Core.merge(backgroundChannels, background);
    }
```

it is a lot faster compared to the double nested loop calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The function `addWeighted` won't work since it will use the same alpha value to all the pixels. To do exactly what you are saying, to only replace the non transparent values in the background, you can create a small function for that, like this:

```
cv::Mat blending(cv::Mat& overlay, cv::Mat& background){
    //must have same size for this to work
    assert(overlay.cols == background.cols && overlay.rows == background.rows);
    cv::Mat result = background.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++){
            cv::Vec4b pix = overlay.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j);
            if (pix[3] == 0){
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(pix[0], pix[1], pix[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am not sure if the transparent value in opencv is 0 or 255, so change it accordingly.... I think it is 0 for non-transparent adn 255 for fully transparent.

If you want to use the value of the alpha channel as a rate to blend, then change it a little to this:

```
cv::Mat blending(cv::Mat& overlay, cv::Mat& background){
    //must have same size for this to work
    assert(overlay.cols == background.cols && overlay.rows == background.rows);
    cv::Mat result = background.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++){
            cv::Vec4b pix = overlay.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j);
            double alphaRate = 1.0 - pix[3]/255.0;
            result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = (1.0 - alphaRate) * cv::Vec3b(pix[0], pix[1], pix[2]) + result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) * alphaRate;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sorry for the code being in C++ and not in JAVA, but I think you can get an idea. Basically is just a loop in the pixels and changing the pixels in the copy of background to those of the overlay if they are not transparent.

*** EDIT ***

I will answer your comment with this edit, since it may take space. The problem is how OpenCV matrix works. For an image with alpha, the data is organized as an array like `BGRA BGRA .... BGRA`, and the basic operations like add, multiply and so on work in matrices with the same dimensions..... you can always try to separate the matrix with split (this will re write the matrix so it may be slow), then change the alpha channel to double (again, rewrite) and then do the multiplication and adding of the matrices. It should be faster since OpenCV optimizes these functions.... also you can do this in GPU....

Something like this:

```
cv::Mat blending(cv::Mat& overlay, cv::Mat& background){
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(overlay, channels);
    channels[3].convertTo(channels[3], CV_64F, 1.0/255.0);
    cv::Mat newOverlay, result;
    cv::merge(channels, newOverlay);
    result = newOverlay * channels[3] + ((1 - channels[3]) * background);
    return result;
}
```

Not sure if OpenCV allows a `CV_8U` to multiply a `CV_64F`, or if this will be faster or not.... but it may be.

Also, the ones with loops has no problem in threads, so it can be optimized... running this in release mode will greatly increase the speed too since the `.at` function of OpenCV does several asserts.... that in release mode are not done. Not sure if this can be change in JAVA though...

Comment: This approach is too slow for me as i am working with 12-megapixel images or larger. Can you provide an implementation using the matrix array functions such as `add()`, `subtract()`, `multiply()`, etc?